# How to handle anorm's Pk deprecation

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Since version 2.3.0 of the anorm library of play framework, the trait `Pk` is deprecated and it suggests the usage of its subclasses `Id` and `NotAssigned` ([documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#anorm.Pk)).

But what if we have a variable that can take either an `Id` or a `NotAssiged`? 
Specifically, in my code I have a `class Person(id: Pk[Long], name: String)`. Using `Pk` as the type of `id`, I can create new users like `Person(NotAssigned, "kostas")` or get existing from my db `Person(Id(3), "kostas")`.

How can I migrate my code to not use the deprecated `Pk` trait, but hold the same functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Pk[A]` is the same as `Option[A]` by structure, where `Id[A](value)` corresponds to `Some[A](value)`, and `NotAssigned` corresponds to `None`.

So the recommended migration would be to use `Option[Long]`, instead. I don't really understand the developers' decision to deprecate `Pk[A]` though, but not `Id[A]` and `NotAssigned`, as both are essentially useless without it. Nonetheless, `Option` will function the same for you, and anorm handles it just the same.

Answer (score 3):

Migration notes are being added about this deprecation: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3029/files . Previous answer is right about Option use.

Best